# How to click on svg icons in protractor?

Tags: automation, protractor

I need to clicking on this icon to perform few edit functions. However, my code is unable to locate this icon. Can somebody help with the correct locators for this snippet?

```
<td _ngcontent-c29="" class="custom-td-action mat-cell cdk-column-action mat-column-action ng-star-inserted" mat-cell="" role="gridcell">
    <button _ngcontent-c29="" aria-haspopup="true" mat-icon-button="" class="mat-icon-button">
        <span class="mat-button-wrapper">
            <mat-icon _ngcontent-c29="" class="inv-icon-size--small mat-icon mat-icon-no-color" role="img" svgicon="inv-ellipsis-h" aria-hidden="true">
                <svg width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 17 3" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" fit="" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet" focusable="false">
                    <!-- Generator: sketchtool 51.3 (57544) - http://www.bohemiancoding.com/sketch -->
                    <title>E1FE60C0-EF43-4EE7-AF32-E28F60D7C746@1,5x</title>
                    <desc>Created with sketchtool.</desc>
                    <defs></defs>
                    <g id="UX-DESIGNER" stroke="none" stroke-width="1" fill="none" fill-rule="evenodd">
                        <g id="ui-03list_02--spec--product-type" transform="translate(-1493.000000, -589.000000)"
                            fill="#333333">
                            <g id="list/product-type-copy-2" transform="translate(255.000000, 547.000000)">
                                <g id="Group-10" transform="translate(185.000000, 18.000000)">
                                    <g id="package/list">
                                        <g id="ico/options" transform="translate(1053.000000, 24.000000)">
                                            <g id="Group-4">
                                                <circle id="Oval" cx="1.5" cy="1.5" r="1.5"></circle>
                                                <circle id="Oval-Copy" cx="8.5" cy="1.5" r="1.5"></circle>
                                                <circle id="Oval-Copy-2" cx="15.5" cy="1.5" r="1.5"></circle>
                                            </g>
                                        </g>
                                    </g>
                                </g>
                            </g>
                        </g>
                    </g>
                </svg>
            </mat-icon>
        </span>
        <div class="mat-button-ripple mat-ripple mat-button-ripple-round" matripple=""></div>
        <div class="mat-button-focus-overlay"></div>
    </button>
    <mat-menu _ngcontent-c29="" xposition="before" class="ng-tns-c9-43">
        <!---->
    </mat-menu>
</td>
```

Unable to click on svg icon for edit functions.

Answer (score 0):

try following xpath:

```
//button[@class='mat-icon-button']//mat-icon/*[name()='svg']
```

Comment: Can you specify what part is not working and what is your goal? This locator is finding the svg element and if you wish to click on it, click function will be executed.

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.